# How to debounce inside a react useLayoutEffect?

Tags: reactjs

When a user is resizing the window, the width shall be set every 1000 ms. I tried to use a lodash debounce, but somehow it is not fired or not fiered with a delay. How do I need to change the code?

My code:
[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-8mmeh?file=/demo.js)

```
const Viewport = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const handleWindowResize = () => {
      debounce(() => {
        const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

        setWidth(windowWidth);
        console.log("windowWidth", windowWidth);
      }, 1000);
    };

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleWindowResize);
    handleWindowResize();
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleWindowResize);
  }, []);

  return <div>Window width: {width}</div>;
};

export default Viewport;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to wrap the debounce function in another function

```
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const handleWindowResize = debounce(() => {
      const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
      setWidth(windowWidth);
    }, 1000);

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleWindowResize);
    handleWindowResize();
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleWindowResize);
  }, []);
```

`debounce` already return another function, that you can pass to the event listener directly.